# In Payum How can I check "correctly" the status "pending" in the payment?

Tags: php, paypal, payum

In my actual Symfony2 project I use PayumBundle, with Payum 1.3.4, to make payments with paypal_express_checkout factory. I found a behavior that maybe it's ok, but I need to confirm with another person who know about Payum.

It's simply to explain:

1- It was created an user in Paypal Sandbox to test the payments, and it was activated the Payment Review to force that all the payments stay in "pending" state.

2- The Prepare stage passed OK, redirected to PayPal.

3- The payment in PayPal fine too, redirected again to my site to the done stage.

4- In the done stage occurs the following:

```
public function doneAction(Request $request)
{
    $token = $this->get('payum')->getHttpRequestVerifier()->verify($request);

    $gateway = $this->get('payum')->getGateway($token->getGatewayName());

    $gateway->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));

    /** @var Payment $payment */
    $payment = $status->getFirstModel();

    ....
}
```

At this point, `$status->getValue()` is equal to **"captured"**.
But in `$payment->getDetails()` I can see this (chuncked for clarity):

```
details(
    "INVNUM" => "57dc5ce455d5a",
    ...
    "ACK" => "Success",
    ...
    "CHECKOUTSTATUS" => "PaymentActionCompleted"
    ...
    "PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS" => "Pending",
    "PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON" => "paymentreview",
    ...
)
```

Payum says the status is Captured, but PayPal (wich is ok) says the paymen is "Pending".

So, why Payum status is "captured" and not "pending"? It this right?

How can I check "correctly" the status "pending" in the payment?

I checked the examples in Payum Bundle Sandbox but there is nothing about the pending status.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the issue thread in GitHub:  https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/585

It is opened at this time, but there I described a shortcut.